# How can I read the output of a subprocess without printing it in the shell of the parent process?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, stdout

I want to start an API in my python script, wait until it has started properly (it will output "API ready") and then send it some requests. Here is what I have tried:

```
api_cmd = "python3 api.py"

# Begin by starting API.
    api_process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(api_cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    subprocess_pids.append(api_process.pid)

    # Wait until API has started
    print("Starting API...")
    while True:
        line = api_process.stdout.readline().decode('ascii')

        if "API ready" in line:
            print("API started! Wait 3 more seconds...")
            time.sleep(3)
            break
        else:
            print("Line: {}".format(line))
```

This works if I set PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 as an environment variable. However, it has to undesired effects:

1. It outputs the subprocesses output in the shell in which I run this script.
2. I can not read the last line (which says "API ready") but only the one before that as the last line does not have a newline character.

Can someone tell me how to fix this behaviour? I tried read() instead of readline() but that somehow wouldn't work.

The output is not due to the print statement in the while loop, as it doesn't start with "Line:" and also continues after the while loop has terminated. Also, the output read by readline() seems to be different than what is printed in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

The output on the shell was output to stderr. I only piped the output of stdout. Fixed it by adding `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`:

```
api_process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(api_cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```